# Wrong url in Typo3 Form

Tags: typo3

I am using a plugin where which defines a list and a detail page. These are different pages in TYPO3. For the detail page, the URL is dynamic and defined the following:

```
routePath: '/{property}'
```

I also want to configure a contact form on this page. Now I face the problem, that the URL of the page is:

```
".../detail-page/my-unique-part"
```

But the action URL of the form is just

```
".../detail-page?...parameter for the form"
```

So the page itself is okay and the contact form is working but the plugin is unable to load the content because the unique identifier is missing.

Comment: Just a small thought, wouldn't this help https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Config/proto/formElements/formElementTypes/Form.html#renderingoptions-addquerystring

Comment: @Siva works, thanks. Do you want to provide this as official answer?

Comment: I added this as an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can bed solved by adding `addQueryString: true` in your forms YAML configuration. Kindly have a look at this [link](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Config/proto/formElements/formElementTypes/Form.html#renderingoptions-addquerystring) for more info.